# jQgrid after save callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have created a jQgrid and want it to call a callback function once a new row is added or some content is edited in the grid

```
jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
        url: '/testGrid/sample?q=5', 
        datatype: "json", 
        mtype: 'POST',
        jsonReader: {
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            root: "rows",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "name",
            userdata: 'userdata'
        },
        width: 775,
          colNames: ['Salaried Employees', '# of FTEs', 'Budget', 'Actuals to Date', 'Invoice Salary'],
          colModel: [
            {name:'salEmp',index:'salEmp', width:100, align: 'left', width:100,editable:false,editrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'FTE',index:'FTE', width:100, align: 'center', editable:false,required:true,editrules:{required:true,number:true}},
            {name:'Budget',index:'Budget', width:100, align: 'right', width:100,editable:false,required:true,editrules:{required:true,number:true}},
            {name:'actDate',index:'actDate', width:100, align: 'right', align:"right",editable:false,required:true,editrules:{required:true,number:true}},
            {name:'invSal',index:'invSal', width:100, align:"right",editable:true,required:true,editrules:{required:true,number:true}}                                        
           ],
            rowNum: 5,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            autoencode: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            sortable: false,
            height: '100%',
            pager: jQuery('#pager1'),
            cellEdit: false,
            cellsubmit: 'remote',
            //cellurl: '/testGrid/sample',

            //call onclick of save
            editurl:"/testGrid/sample",
            gridview: true,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true
        })
        // Pager options for Subgrid
        .navGrid('#pager1',{
            add:false,
            edit:false,
            del:true,
            search:false,
            refresh:false,
            deltext: 'Delete'
        });
$('#list1').jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager1',{
            addtext: "Add",
            edittext: "Edit",
            savetext: "Save",
            canceltext: "Cancel",                       
            addParams: { 
                position: "afterSelected"
            },
            addedrow:'last'

        });
```

Comment: The code which you posted don't contain any editing. The answer on your question depend on which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you want to use: cell editing, inline editing or form editing. Additionally jqGrid provide many options of usage of inline editing and form editing like [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav), [formatter: "actions"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) etc.

Comment: **The callbacks which you need are different for different kind of editing modes and different implementation variants**. So you have to decide first which editing mode and which implementation version more corresponds the requirements of your project.

Comment: @Oleg - i will be using cell based editing eventually this is more of POC to explore jQgrid

Comment: What is "POC"? As I wrote before every implementation of editing provide callbacks, but the callbacks **are different**. So if you decide to use cell editing instead you need use *another* callbacks. Moreover you should specify more exact at what moment you need your callback by called: before editing started, directly after started, before saving, after saving etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`inlineNav` allows to specify the callbacks of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) used for inline editing. To specify the callbacks one can use `editParams` and `addParams.addRowParams` options:

```
var myEditOptions = {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
            alert("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is editing.");
        },
        aftersavefunc: function (rowid, response, options) {
            alert("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is successfuly modified.");
        }
    };

$('#list1').jqGrid('inlineNav','#pager1', {
    addtext: "Add",
    edittext: "Edit",
    savetext: "Save",
    canceltext: "Cancel",                       
    addParams: { 
        position: "afterSelected",
        addRowParams: myEditOptions
    },
    addedrow: "last",
    editParams: myEditOptions
});
```

Comment: @Varun: It's unclear for me what part of the answer is not clear for you. There are only [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) where you the options of `inlineNav` and `editRow` are described and the full source code of both methods which you can find [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js).